# Availability of the S'dei Chemed

Tags: books-generally, internet

I heard a couple years ago that someone had begun a new, laser printed, annotated edition of the [שדי חמד](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99#.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.95). Did this happen?

Is the full text of *S'dei Chemed* available anywhere online?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx

Comment: @Dave @Gershon Gold Together you have shown me the error of my ways. I thought there was only one field when indeed there are multiple and have therefore edited the question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The](http://hebrewbooks.org/14146) [answer](http://hebrewbooks.org/14153) [to](http://hebrewbooks.org/14154) [the](http://hebrewbooks.org/14145) [second](http://hebrewbooks.org/14150) [question](http://hebrewbooks.org/14157) [is](http://hebrewbooks.org/14155) [partially](http://hebrewbooks.org/14156) [yes](http://hebrewbooks.org/14151).

Comment: Very clever ,with the hyper links +1 just for that!